# Recursive method in java stack overflow

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow

I am getting a stackoverflow in the following code:

```
private static boolean haveBeen(int k, int t,ArrayList <int[]> arr, int i){
    if(!(i==arr.size ())) {
        if (arr.get (i)[0] == k && arr.get (i)[1] == t)
            return true;
        return (haveBeen (k, t, arr, i + 1));
    }
    return false;
}
```

Arrays in `arr` are all populated with (populated) int[2]. (Trying to iterate over array to see if `k`,`t` do exist).
TIA

Comment: What is the initial value of `i`?

Comment: 0 :)))))))))))))))))

Comment: Other notes: recursion is not needed here. A loop would work. Also, `if(!(i==arr.size ())) {` could be written more clearly as `if (i !=arr.size ()) {`. Lastly, [Function Return writing style in Java](//stackoverflow.com/a/4216741)

Comment: Gotta recurse...

Comment: Ok. Can you create a [mcve]? I tried your code and it seems to work: https://ideone.com/8K96xB

Comment: It's silly to use recursion for this function.  If you have to, for some silly reason, then limit the stack requirements to O(log N) by dividing the array into halves and recursing on each half.

Answer (score 0):

```
//prince needs to catch villain in shortest path from initial coordinates i,j, in 
//square matrix of non negative ints .Can move to adjacent squares if 
//-2<(square-adjacent square)<3. returns -1 if no path exists. villain is -1.
public static int prince(int[][] drm, int i, int j){
        ArrayList<int[]> firstSquare = new ArrayList<int[]>();
        int[] currentCoordinates = {i,j};
        firstSquare.add (currentCoordinates);
        int returnValue = recursePrince (drm,i,j,0,0,firstSquare) ;
        if (returnValue == drm.length*drm.length)
           return -1;
        return returnValue;
    }


    private static int recursePrince(int[][] drm, int i, int j, int nextSquareX, int nextSquareY, ArrayList <int[]> visitedSquares) {
        int minPathLength=drm.length*drm.length;
        int[] currentCoordinates = {i,j};
        visitedSquares.add (currentCoordinates);
        ArrayList<int[]> visitedSquaresCopy = (ArrayList<int[]>) visitedSquares.clone ();
        if (drm[nextSquareX][nextSquareY]==-1) //exit condition
            return 0;
        if (drm.length > i+1)//go right
            if (isLegal (drm[i][j], drm[i + 1][j]) && !(haveBeen (i + 1, j, visitedSquaresCopy, 0))) {
                minPathLength = Math.min (recursePrince (drm, i, j, i + 1, j, visitedSquaresCopy) + 1, minPathLength);
            }        if (i-1 > -1)//go left
            if (isLegal (drm[i][j], drm[i - 1][j]) && !(haveBeen (i -1, j, visitedSquaresCopy, 0)))
                minPathLength = Math.min (recursePrince (drm, i, j, i - 1, j, visitedSquaresCopy)+1,minPathLength);
        if (drm[0].length> j+1)//go up
            if (isLegal (drm[i][j], drm[i][j+1]) && !(haveBeen (i, j+1, visitedSquaresCopy, 0)))
                minPathLength = Math.min (recursePrince (drm, i, j, i, j+1, visitedSquaresCopy)+1,minPathLength);
        if (j-1>-1)//go down
            if (isLegal (drm[i][j], drm[i][j-1]) && !(haveBeen (i, j-1, visitedSquaresCopy, 0)))
                minPathLength = Math.min (recursePrince (drm, i, j, i , j-1, visitedSquaresCopy)+1,minPathLength);
        return Math.min(drm.length*2,minPathLength);// Larger than max possible path so will represent NO PATH FOUND.
    }
    private static boolean haveBeen(int k, int t,ArrayList <int[]> arr, int i){
        if(!(i==arr.size ())) {
            if (arr.get (i)[0] == k && arr.get (i)[1] == t)
                return true;
            return (haveBeen (k, t, arr, i + 1));
        }
        return false;
    }
     private static boolean isLegal(int currRoofVal,int adjcRoofVal){
        return ((currRoofVal - adjcRoofVal<=2) && (currRoofVal-adjcRoofVal>=0)) || (adjcRoofVal-currRoofVal==1) || adjcRoofVal==-1;

     }
```

Comment: Edited - villain = -1 (3rd line)